# Swift sorted(by:) method doesn't correctly sort an array of struct based on integer

Tags: swift, sorting, swiftui

I need to sort an array of some custom struct objects. My structure contains a "user_id" Int value, which is the one I have to use to sort the array. So far, nothing really exciting.

And then I have to force one item (based on its user_id) to stay on top of my list, ie. as the first element of my sorted array.

I came with the current code:

```swift
myArray.sorted(by: { $0.user_id == 40 ? true : $0.user_id < $1.user_id })
```

but sometimes (not always) the array seems to totally ignore the first comparison and just sort items based on their user_id. So for example if my list has the elements 37, 40, 41, it'll be either sorted as [40, 37, 41] or [37, 40, 41] and I can't find why or how.

For the context: I use this list in a dynamic var (I forgot how they are called) in a SwiftUI view, which uses a ForEach(mySortedArray) to build a VStack of sorted custom rows. So basically the SwiftUI code looks like that (BoardMember being my custom struct):

```swift
    @State private var boardPerms: [BoardMember] = []

    func fetchMembers() {
        boardPerms = ...
    }

    var displayedMembers: [BoardMember] {
        boardPerms.sorted(by: { $0.user_id == 40 ? true : $0.user_id < $1.user_id })
    }

    var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(displayedMembers) { member in
            ...
        }
        .onAppear(perform: fetchMembers)
    }
```

and I can assure the issue is in the `displayedMembers` var, because I also tried to debug it with the following code inside my body: `Text((displayedMembers.map{$0.user_id.description}).joined(separator: " "))`

Any idea what's wrong with my comparison? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate to [Array.sorted(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) requires that you

> return true if its first argument should be ordered before its second argument; otherwise, false.

The order of the arguments passed to the predicate can be given in either order (`(a, b)` *or* `(b, a)`) depending on how the list has been sorted so far, but the predicate *must* give a consistent result in either order or else you'll get nonsense results.

In your predicate, you're checking the *first* element's user ID to prioritize it, but *not* the second; i.e., you're handling `(a, b)` but *not* `(b, a)`. If you update your predicate to

```swift
myArray.sorted(by: {
    // The order of the checking here matters. Specifically, the predicate
    // requires a `<` relationship, not a `<=` relationship. If both $0 and $1
    // have the same `user_id`, we need to return `false`. Checking $1.user_id
    // first hits two birds with one stone.
    if $1.user_id == 40 {
        return false
    } else if $0.user_id == 40 {
        return true
    }
    
    return $0.user_id < $1.user_id
})
```

then you'll get consistent results.

Alternatively, if the element is known ahead of time, you can avoid this by extracting it from the list and sorting the remaining results.

Comment: Ohh I totally didn't think about sorting (b,a), thanks a lot!
And yeah I'll consider separating the 1st element from the rest of the list, nice idea

Comment: Shouldn't  the predicate return `false` for two *equal* elements, e.g. if both user ids are 40?

Comment: @MartinR That's true, though it sounds like `user_id` is a unique value. It also depends on whether a stable ordering matters, since if you have `n` copies of the same value, sorting this will bubble them all up to the beginning of the list, just in an unstable order. I'll update the answer to include that, though.

Comment: It becomes simpler if you test `if $1.user_id == 40` first :)

Comment: The predicate is required to be a “strict weak ordering over the elements” and in particular irreflexive. I have no idea what can happen if that is not satisfied.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, fixed the typo. This is what I get for coding in a browser ‍♂️